# When to subscribe to events in Vue lifecycle

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a component in Vue2 with vue-component with a subcomponent

```
  <note :bus="bus" :itemId="selectedId"></note>
```

which looks like this

```
  <textarea v-model="text"></textarea>
```

The subcomponent registers to events

```
created() {
  if (this.bus != null) {
    this.bus.$on('store', () => {
      this.store()
    });
  }
}
```

and the component does

```
  this.bus.$emit('store')
```

to trigger store in all subcomponents.

Now the first time store is called once. On the second edit it's called twice, etc. So I guess there are more subcomponents created each time. Or I have to deregister from the bus? Or I'm registering with the bus in the wrong lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 1):

Now works with

```
beforeDestroy() {
  if (this.bus != null) {
    this.bus.$off('store', this.store);
  }
}
```